# The new flood lights I have do not appear to be making contact at the center of the socket

Tags: lighting

The older halogen lights I have that work appear to have longer thread length on the bulbs.  I eye-balled about a 1/8" - 1/4" difference in thread length with the new bulbs having shorter thread length.  I cannot find specification that addresses thread length on flood light bulbs (or any other bulb for that matter).  I have tried some adapters that are advertised as lengthening the socket but their threads were similar to the threads on the new bulbs.  I ordered bulbs that were listed as "long neck". Same problem.

How can I fit new lamps in that socket?

Comment: I don't see a question in there. Can you [edit] and add a summary or highlight this with an answerable question?

Comment: And perhaps a photo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are these LEDs? They often have a wide base which collides with something other than the socket itself.

Answer (score 2):

Likely, the continued pressure of a hot incandescent lamp pushed in that contact a bit.  The *center* metal contact in most screw-type (Edison-base) sockets is a *spring* that can easily be pried up *slightly*. **N.B.** Be absolutely sure the **correct** circuit breaker is **off** before attempting this.

[image: Prying up metal contact -- my own photo]

It is also possible to put a blob of solder on a fixed center contact, if that is within your capabilities.

Of course, another alternative is to replace the lamp socket.